# how to send data back to and fro from controller to view. and view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

i have the below code in mvc.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult RegionHeaderItem(int regionId)
    {
        var objectvalue = ViewData["RegionDashboardHeader"];        


        if (objectvalue != null )
        {

            IDictionary<int, bool> sessionItem = (IDictionary<int, bool>)objectvalue; 

            if (sessionItem.ContainsKey(regionId))
            {
                sessionItem[regionId] = !sessionItem[regionId];
            }
            else
            {
                sessionItem.Add(regionId, true);
            }
            ViewData["RegionDashboardHeader"] = sessionItem;

        }
        else
        {
            objectvalue = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
            IDictionary<int, bool> sessionItem = (IDictionary<int, bool>)objectvalue;
            sessionItem.Add(regionId, true);
            ViewData["RegionDashboardHeader"] = sessionItem;


        }

        var regionVMObj = this.GetRegionDetails(regionId);
        return PartialView(regionVMObj);

    }
```

and have the following code in Views.

var objectvalue = ViewData["RegionDashboardHeader"];

```
var objectvalue = ViewData["RegionDashboardHeader"];
    var sessionItem = (IDictionary<int, bool>)objectvalue;
    var display = sessionItem == null ? false : sessionItem.ContainsKey(Model.Id) ? sessionItem[Model.Id] : false;
```

Basically what i am doing is i am sending some object from controller to view and keeping that object in *viewdata* and using the data to display when user clicks *+ and -* expand buttons.

I am able to expand it perfectly. now when i collapse i hit the same method RegionHeaderItem 
I want to bring back the data that is views when i collapse and check for data nulls.

issue i am able to expand but while collapse *objectvalue* is again setting back to null.

can any one help in achieving this?

Comment: Your first line of code - `var objectvalue = ViewData["RegionDashboardHeader"];` makes no sense - it will always be `null` (`ViewData` is for sending data from a controller to a view - its is disposed once the method exits and the view has been sent to the browser)

Comment: Yes , i understand that, is there any alternative way to write that line. earlier i use to write  Session["ContractPaymentHeader"] but since i am using dot net core now i dont have the accessabiliy to Session["ContractPaymentHeader"] . it is not included in the current library .

Answer (score -1):

Use viewmodels not objects when u send to a view.

use post to receive data back to controller from a submit button in the view!